# I am trying to declare a Package to add 2 4-bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR and return a 4-bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR Result and 1-bit Carry

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, hdl

I an using Xilinx ISE Tool for it.

STEPS FOLLOWED:-

1. Created a Project in Xilinx ISE.
2. Added VHDL Package as a Source.
3. Wrote Code to declare the Package to add two 4-bit STD_LOGIC_VECTORs and return a 4-bit STD_LOGIC_VECTOR Result and a 1-bit STD_LOGIC Carry.
4. Added another New Source (VHDL Module) to the Project to simply write Code to see if my package works fine.
5. Wrote a Test-bench to Verify the DUT by adding another New Source (VHDL Test Bench) to the DUT.

When I checks Behavioral Check Syntax for the TB, it compiled with 2 WARNINGS:

WARNING 1:- Line 39: Subprogram <"+"> does not conform with its declaration.
WARNING 2:- Line 39: Function "+" does not always return a value.

I Simulated (using Simulate Behavioral Model) the TB anyway, but NO WAVEFORM IS BEING SHOWN.

Please guide me to resolve this.

VHDL PACKAGE:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

package my_package is

function "+" (a,b : std_logic_vector)
return std_logic_vector;

end package my_package;

package body my_package is

function "+" (a,b : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0))
return std_logic_vector is
    
variable result : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0) := "0000";
variable carry : std_logic := '0';

begin

for i in a'reverse_range loop
result(i) := a(i) xor b(i) xor carry;
carry := (a(i) and b(i)) or (b(i) and carry) or (a(i) and carry);
end loop;
end "+";

end package body my_package;
```

VHDL MODULE:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.my_package.all;

entity my_package_check is
Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
B : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
C : in  STD_LOGIC;
res : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
Cout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end my_package_check;

architecture Behavioral of my_package_check is
SIGNAL Z : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (4 downto 0);
begin
Z <= A + B;
res <= Z (3 downto 0);
Cout <= Z(4);
end Behavioral;
```

VHDL TEST BENCH:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY my_package_checktb IS
END my_package_checktb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF my_package_checktb IS 

COMPONENT my_package_check
PORT(
C : IN std_logic;
A : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
B : IN std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
res : OUT std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
Cout : OUT std_logic
);
END COMPONENT;

SIGNAL C :  std_logic :='0';
SIGNAL A :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
SIGNAL B :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) := "0000";
             
SIGNAL Cout :  std_logic;
SIGNAL res :  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
          

BEGIN

uut: my_package_check PORT MAP(
A => A,
B => B,
C => C,
res => res,
Cout => Cout
);

A <= "0000", "1111" after 100 ns;
B <= "0000", "1111" after 100 ns;

END;
```

NOTE:- AS PROVIDENG TEST VECTORS FOR INPUTS via STIMULUS PROCEESS, was throwing in ERROS, I used a different Method to provide the Test Vectors.

AIM:- To get the Output Waveform and verify the functionality of the "+" Function declared in Package.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-1993 8.12 Return statement "A return statement is used to complete the execution of the innermost enclosing function or procedure body." ...  "A return statement appearing in a function body must have an expression." ... "It is an error if execution of a function completes by any means other than the execution of a return statement."

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `"+"` function does not have a return statement. It needs to end with:

```vhdl
Return carry & result;
```

Note: Vhdl already has arithmetic functions in the `numeric_std` package

Comment: Thank you. I did edit my Code for the Package and the error seems to have been resolved. Now the issue is that, the waveform is showing UUUU for the Result and the Simulation for Carry Output is also not correct. To my knowledge the Loop used is correct.                                               Note:- not using numeric_std package to get hans-on with making package.